# can't use Nodemon on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, nodemon

I am using ubuntu with node 12.6 npm 6.13. I installed nodemon using

```
npm i -g nodemon
```

it installs successfully

`+ nodemon@2.0.2 added 105 packages from 49 contributors in 25.001s`

however whenever use is 
    `nodemon server.js`
it throws an error 
`nodemon: command not found`.
how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `ampersand (&)` from the export and that should properly add it to the end of the existing PATH variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/npm
printf "%s\n" "$PATH"
```

Maybe try switch to the root user with `sudo su -` and then add to the PATH, and then do the global install (won't need **sudo** then of course):

```
sudo su -
export PATH=$PATH:/home/twoscoops/npm
npm install -g --force nodemon
```

Comment: now it says npm not installed. can you explain what do you think the problem is with nodemon.  I am facing same issue with create-react-app it seems like no globally installed package is recognized.

Comment: Please run this command because it is saying npm not installed ```npm install --save-dev nodemon```